# Regular expression - find from start to end but only first match

Tags: php, regex

I need to find two words in text, and replace text between. So I have this regular expression:

```
(START[a-zA-Z\s]+STOP)
```

and this text:

> banana car **START house apple computer STOP** mouse money

(bold text is matched).

But when I have multiple STOP words, then this match to the last one, because STOP is also [a-zA-Z\s] pattern.

> banana car **START house apple computer STOP mouse money STOP** orange

How I can change this regular expression to stop matching at first appearance of word? This is what I need to get:

> banana car **START house apple computer STOP** mouse money STOP orange

Comment: This will give you information on the issue, http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html. You could use the `U` modifier to alter the behavior of the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding a `?` after `+`. So use this pattern:

```
/(START[a-zA-Z\s]+?STOP)/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iC9uR4/6)

Your pattern *(without `?`)* matches first `STOP` as `[a-zA-Z\s]+`.

Comment: So simple. Thank You very much!